# If ${L_1} \subseteq {L_2}$ and and $L_1$ is union of continuous curves and $L_2$be algebraic curve. Can we say that $L_1$ is piecewise $C^∞$ curve?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, algebraic-curves

Let $L_2=\{(x,y):x,y\in R,f(x,y)=0\}$ be algebraic curve, and $f(x,y)$ is polynomial.

If ${L_1} \subseteq {L_2}$ and  $L_1$ is union of continuous curves. Can we say that $L_1$ is piecewise $C^∞$ curve?